# How do I copy two sets of data to clipboard (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, copy, copy-paste

I have two sets of data I am trying to copy to clipboard. An audio file and a string. I can't get to copy them both, but each individually works. Here is the code I have to set the data and copy it:

.h

```
@property NSData *previewData;
@property NSString *linkData;
```

.m

```
NSArray *preview = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.previewUrl"];
NSArray *linkData = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"results.url"];

_previewData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[preview objectAtIndex:0]]];
_linkData = [linkData objectAtIndex:0];

// Need to combine these two lines
[pasteboard setData:_previewData forPasteboardType:@"public.mpeg-4-audio"];
pasteboard.string = _linkData;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the `string` property of a `UIPasteBoard` it replaces all current items.  You need to set the `items` property, which takes an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents an item to be added to the pasteboard -

```
NSDictionary *imageItem=@{@"public.mpeg-4-audio":self.previewData};
NSDictionary *textItem=@{@"public.plain-text":self.linkData};

pasteboard.items=@[imageItem,textItem];
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo - I used ',' when it should be ':'. Also I was trying to use constants from core services, but this give a problem with Objective C, so it is easier to just use the literals

Comment: It works! Sorta. I need to delete what is already copied in pasteboard before though

Comment: Sorry, yes. The difference between your original code and addItems is that `addItems` adds to the existing content.

Comment: So I should just use this before those lines since there is no way to clear it: `[pasteboard setValue:@"" forPasteboardType:UIPasteboardNameGeneral];`

Comment: I have updated my answer - you can just assign directly to the `items` property to replace what is already there

Comment: Did you get my last update - I forgot to change the : to = at first

Comment: hey could you please look my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272426/how-do-i-copy-audio-file-to-clipboard-and-send-via-imessage-ios-8