# How do I send audio file send via iMessage ios 8

Tags: ios, audio, custom-keyboard, uipasteboard, imessage

As we know with the launch of ios 8 the apple allow custom Keyboard extension.In keyboard extension we can send images,gif etc in SMS by using Copy image to clipboard.code

```
 UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
 NSData *data= UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"so_close_disappointed_meme.png"]);
 [pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.png"];
```

Now i am trying to send audio file in iMessage like this feature [reference](https://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/messages/).don't know apple will allow us to send audio in iMessage?.so for i tried above approach but it did not show any paste option for audio in SMS window.

```
 UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tune"ofType:@"mp3"];
 NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:path];
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 [pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.mp3"];
```

Any one can suggest me how do we send audio file by using custom keyboard extension.is it possible?

Comment: I never knew that this was possible on iOS devices but this sounds really cool!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you could directly attach the file to `MFMessageComposeViewController`. Here is the [documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MFMessageComposeViewController/addAttachmentData:typeIdentifier:filename:) of how it could be done.

Following would be the steps to do so.

1. Check if file can be send using file UTI using `+
   (BOOL)isSupportedAttachmentUTI:(NSString *)uti`
2. Find File UTI. i.e. path for the file
3. Attach file to  `MFMessageComposeViewController` using `-
   (BOOL)addAttachmentData:(NSData *)attachmentData
   typeIdentifier:(NSString *)uti filename:(NSString *)filename`

As the description for the method says

> This method is especially useful when the attachment you want to add to a message does not have a file system representation. This can be the case, for example, for programmatically composed audiovisual content.

Note : You will have to convert audio file to NSData

Comment: I have tried above approach for sending audio file directly via SMS but still did not achieved the desired result but it help me a a lot and i hope after bit research i will get the desired result.

Comment: Just make sure you have iMessage turned on and associated with a AppleID. Even I might try to create a example if time allows me to :). Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

The MFMessageComposeViewController isn't the solution in this scenario. A custom keyboard extension shouldn't present a new view controller, rather just paste the audio file to the pasteboard. Heres some swift code that worked for me

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("audio", ofType:"wav")
let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
let wavUTI = "com.microsoft.waveform-audio"
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().setData(data!, forPasteboardType: wavUTI)
```